# Raman Spectroscopy and Phonon Modes

Tags: solid-state-physics, phonons, raman-spectroscopy

How can someone use Raman Spectroscopy to obtain information for the phonon modes of a crystal? I am asking for some paper that contains information about Raman Spectroscopy and Phonons from an experimental point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The photon momentum of visible light is small compared to phonon momentum in crystals so one can only see phonons at $\Delta k=0$.

But now there is the technique of (Resonant) X-ray Raman Scattering with resolution high enough to see phonons and magnons and measure their dispersion curves.

[Introduction to High-Resolution Inelastic X-Ray Scattering](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.01098), Baron (2015)